# Severity: Warning --> hash_equals() commerce coinbase integration

Tags: codeigniter-3

ERROR - 2023-11-14 18:55:35 --> Severity: Warning --> hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, null given /home/xhost/website.com/application/controllers/Callback.php 610

```
 $secret = $paymentAPIDetails->webhookToken;
        $headerName = 'X-Cc-Webhook-Signature';
        $headers = getallheaders();
        $signature = isset($headers[$headerName]) ? $headers[$headerName] : null;
        $payload = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        $result = hash_hmac("sha256", $payload, $secret);
610 >   $res = (string) hash_equals($signature, $result);
        $result = $res ? 'true' : 'false';
        if ($res) {
            $payload = json_decode($payload);
            $conversationId = $payload->event->data->metadata->conversationId;
            $json = $payload->event->data->timeline;
            $payment = $this->db->where([
                'conversation_id' => $conversationId,
                'is_active' => 0,
                'is_success' => 0
            ])->get('payment_log')->row();
            if (isset($payment->id)) {
                if ($json[count($json) - 1]->status == "COMPLETED" || $json[count($json) - 1]->status == "RESOLVED") :
                    $this->db->update('payment_log', [
                        'is_success' => 1,
                        'is_active' => 1,
                        'json' => json_encode($json[count($json) - 1]),
                        'user_id' => $payment->user_id
                    ], [
                        'id' => $payment->id
                    ]);
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE `users` SET balance = balance + ? WHERE id = ?", [
                        $payment->price,
                        $payment->user_id
                    ]);
                    insertUserStep($payment->user_id, 'coinbase', [
                        'status' => TRUE,
                        'paid_price' => $payment->price,
                        'add_balance' => $payment->price
                    ]);
                    
                else :
                    $this->db->update('payment_log', [
                        'is_success' => 0,
                        'is_active' => 0,
                        'json' => json_encode($json[count($json) - 1]),
                        'user_id' => $payment->user_id
                    ], [
                        'id' => $payment->id
                    ]);
                endif;
            }
        }
```

This integration was working smoothly before. but after php update I get this error.

```
Severity: Warning --> hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, null given /home/xhost/website.com/application/controllers/Callback.php 610
```